# Natural sorting of a list without a definitive type

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm trying to write a dynamic function that takes a collection of one of my custom classes, and sorts the collection based on the property specified in the parameters.

It currently look like this:

```
public void AscendingSort(ObservableCollection<ManifestItem> list, string property)
{
    try
    {
        List<ManifestItem> temp = list.ToList();

        //set the global equal to the result
        manifestData.Manifest_Items = new ObservableCollection<ManifestItem>(temp.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(x)).ToList());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error in Manifest AscendingSort");
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

Here is my ManifestItem class

```
public class ManifestItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [JsonProperty("ttl")]
    private int ttl;

    public int TTL
    {
        get
        {
            return ttl;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ttl != value)
            {
                ttl = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TTL");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("serial")]
    private object serial;

    public object SataType
    {
        get
        {
            return serial;
        }
        set
        {
            if (serial != value)
            {
                serial = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Serial");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    private string id;

    public string ID
    {
        get
        {
            return id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (id != value)
            {
                id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ID");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("formatType")]
    private string formatType;

    public string FormatType
    {
        get
        {
            return formatType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (formatType != value)
            {
                formatType = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FormatType");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("dataType")]
    private string dataType;

    public string DataType
    {
        get
        {
            return dataType;
        }
        set
        {
            if (dataType != value)
            {
                dataType = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DataType");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("modifiedIso8601")]
    private string modifiedIso8601;

    public string ModifiedIso8601
    {
        get
        {
            return modifiedIso8601;
        }
        set
        {
            if (modifiedIso8601 != value)
            {
                modifiedIso8601 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ModifiedIso8601");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("modifiedTimestamp")]
    private object modifiedTimestamp;

    public object ModifiedTimestamp
    {
        get
        {
            return modifiedTimestamp;
        }
        set
        {
            if (modifiedTimestamp != value)
            {
                modifiedTimestamp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ModifiedTimestamp");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("link")]
    private Link link;

    public Link Link
    {
        get
        {
            return link;
        }
        set
        {
            if (link != value)
            {
                link = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Link");
            }
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("returnChannels")]
    private ObservableCollection<object> returnChannels;

    public ObservableCollection<object> ReturnChannels
    {
        get
        {
            return returnChannels;
        }
        set
        {
            if (returnChannels != value)
            {
                returnChannels = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ReturnChannels");
            }
        }
    }

    //Event handling
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

My problem is that it's not in a natural sort order, so i get this:

- a1
- a10
- a2

Instead of this:

- a1
- a2
- a10

As x is an instance of my class, I can't process that in any way. Can I do this without writing an IComparer? I've attempted writing a custom IComparer but fallen at the first hurdle, as I'd need to find a way to include the specified property into my comparison.

Comment: What's so bad about writing an `IComparer`? It's practically trivial to do on the fly by leveraging [`Comparer.Create`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh737198).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, move the reflection stuff to a closure so you don't recompute it for every item:

```
var propertyInfo = x.GetType().GetProperty(property);

manifestData.Manifest_Items = new ObservableCollection<ManifestItem>
(
    temp.OrderBy(x => propertyInfo.GetValue(x)).ToList()
);
```

To get the sort you want, you should implement an `IComparer`, but if you want the ugly solution here it is:

```
var propertyInfo = x.GetType().GetProperty(property);

manifestData.Manifest_Items = new ObservableCollection<ManifestItem>
(
    temp.OrderBy(x =>
    {
        var s = propertyInfo.GetValue(x);
        return s.Substring(0, 1) + s.Substring(1).PadLeft(4, '0');
    }).ToList()
);
```

Nothing fancy. This solution will accommodate numbers from A1 to Z9999.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Had to change a few things to get it to work, the propertyInfo variable ended up as `var propertyInfo = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0].GetProperty(property);` , and the return value for the sort ended up being `return Regex.Replace(s, "[0-9]+", match => match.Value.PadLeft(10, '0'));`